# 'ls' is not recognized in Anaconda Python 2.7 Spyder

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I run my codes in Anaconda Spyder Python 2.7 for Windows 7 64bits.

But when I run this code:

```
!ls -lh ./training3.crfsuite
```

I received this error:

```
'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone know why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ls` is a *nix command, and is not installed under Windows by default. Use `dir` and its appropriate options instead.

Comment: I changed it to ---> dir  ('./training3.crfsuite') and no error anymore. So that, it saved my model to this folder?

Comment: I think you can use the `%ls` magic on Spyder's IPython consoles.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba worth noting there is no `%ls` magic command it and it's almost certainly getting delegated to `!ls` instead

Comment: I am getting a similar problem. When I change the directory to Downloads; 'ls' command reports "operation not permitted" while it works on "Home" and Desktop. I have installed Anaconda in MAC.

Answer (score 14):

You can install the m2-base utilities using Anaconda Prompt command line and you will have the basic Linux commands.:

```
conda install m2-base
```